# Azure DevOps hosted agents failing nuget restore

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, docker-build

Randomly it seems that Azure DevOps hosted agents cannot restore from nuget. It seems to fail at its first attempt to hit `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` and then it tries another 3rd party source I have in my `nuget.config`. Has anyone found a work around for this? Most of the time a rerun will fix it, but other times it take 3 or 4 before it will finally complete. Today I also have a Docker build (in DevOps) failing on the same step and it just won't get past it.

Comment: do you haven any logs? What pipelines is this classic or yaml? Is there more in you nuget.config... where is this config stored. Computers never do something randomly, we humans just have to figure out what caused the deviation in outcome ;-)

Comment: In this case it's using classic.

Here is the nuget config with the credentials obfuscated.

```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="api.nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="Telerik-Nuget" value="https://nuget.telerik.com/nuget" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <Telerik-Nuget>
      <add key="Username" value="xxx" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="xxx" />
    </Telerik-Nuget>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Comment: In principle, I agree, computers shouldn't be random, but if the same action results in different endings then pseudorandom is close enough for my description here. Also, here is a snippet from the logs ```Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://nuget.telerik.com/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Win32.Primitives'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
```. You can see it's trying Telerik, but those are packages that shouldn't even be tried there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you need to make sure you have package sourcing enabled so nuget will make sure to pull from the correct place. Apparently it's a new feature in nuget 6.0. To opt-in you need to add the following to your nuget.config as seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-source-mapping).

```
<packageSourceMapping>
 <packageSource key="api.nuget.org">
  <package pattern="*" />
 </packageSource>
 <packageSource key="3rdPartySource">
   <package pattern="3rdPartySource.*" />
 </packageSource>
</packageSourceMapping>
```